# How to substitute match() with fmatch() in Rprofile.site?

Tags: r

I want to replace the default `match()` function with `fmatch()` which is faster. The following code works in R console

```
match<-fmatch

unlockBinding('match', baseenv())
assign("match", fastmatch::fmatch, envir = baseenv())
```

However, when I put either piece code in the Rprofile.site, it always gives an error. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Put the code into a `.First` function and save it in the default workspace file `.Rdata` in your user directory.

```
.First <- function()
{
    ## Unless you unlock the binding, you can't change 
    ## an object in a locked namespace.
    unlockBinding('match', baseenv())
    assign("match", fastmatch::fmatch, envir = baseenv())
}
```

Comment: Unless you unlock the binding, you can't change an object in a locked namespace.

Comment: Could you explain more on why `.RData` works while `Rpfofile.site` doesn't?

Comment: I saved the `.First` function in the default workspace with name `.Rdata`, but the `.First` function is not executed while R restores this `.RData`. I have to run `.First()` manually to substitute `match()`. Any comments?